# Subspace of global sections of a line bundle that generate at every stalk

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let us have a scheme $X$ over a field $k$ and a line bundle $\mathscr{L}$ on $X$. Let $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{L})$ be an $n$ dimensional vector space over $k$. Can we have $m<n$ sections that generate? That is to say can we have a surjective morphism $\mathscr{O}_X^m\to \mathscr{L}$ that is surjective even though $m<n$.

This seems counterintuitive to me, but I cannot seem to rule out the possibility, as we know that $\Gamma(X,\mathscr{O}_X^m)\to \Gamma(X,\mathscr{L})$ is not necessarily surjective.

So my question is can the above happen? And if so I would appreciate an example to better wrap my head around where my reasoning went wrong. Also are there situations inthe above situation, we can conclude $m=n$?

Thank you

Comment: Ok, so $\mathscr{O}(2)$ on $\mathbb{P}^1$ is an example of the above as the global sections $x^2,y^2$ generate at every stalk, but there are three global sections. I would still appreciate if someone could explain the phenomenon though.

Comment: Not quite sure what kind of explanation you're after. We just need for each point for there to be a section of the subspace not in the maximal ideal. Maybe it's that this is an example of the phenomenon that a sheaf map needn't be surjective on global sections to be surjective? Geometrically, if the sheaf $\mathscr L$ is globally generated to begin with, then a choice of basis for $\Gamma(X, \mathscr L)$ gives a map to $\mathbb P^{n-1}$; any projection from $\mathbb P^n$ from a point not on the image identifies a smaller-dimensional subspace of sections that still generate (define a morphism).